# Firefox 21.0 HTML5 Video

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video

Can I vent for a minute -- Mozilla released Firefox 21.0 not long ago and it's *supposed* support for H.264 video is confusing to say the least.

I noticed that FF21 changes the HTML5 video tag to an object tag when the page loads.

This code that I wrote ...

```
<video controls='controls' preload='none' width='320' height='240'>
    <source src='test.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

... automagically becomes this code after the page loads ...

```
<object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-ms-wmp" uimode="full">
    <param name="autostart" value="false">
    <param name="url" value="test.mp4">
</object>
```

Why does FF21 change the code from VIDEO to OBJECT?  I'm on Windows 7, so I'm not surprised my HTML5 video becomes an IE player -- but is this true HTML5 support?

By the way, this isn't a big deal if you've hard-coded the URL of the video file into the source attribute.  But if you're loading the video dynamically, does this mean developers have to start manipulating the PARAM/URL attribute instead of the VIDEO/SOURCE attribute IF the user is using FF21+ on Windows7?  My if/else statements for loading the proper video file are growing with every new browser release/upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Running FF21 on Windows 7 here - not seeing this behavior. The page loads, the video plays and Firebug shows the `video` tag intact. Could this be caused by an add-on / extension?

Comment: Thanks for testing it and you're right.  I did have the [Windows Media Player Extension For Firefox](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/html5-extension-for-wmp-plugin) add-on installed.  It appears that add-on was modifying the video tags.  It says it enables Firefox users to play H.264-encoded videos so I thought I needed it -- but I guess not.

Comment: You don't need that extension with the latest version of firefox.  You did prior with previous versions.  As you can see, it converted the video tag to an object tag so that windows media player would play it for firefox.